# manually entered data in firebase issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am manually entering in data into my database and the only variable not getting passed from my database is the author and I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
func getAllArticles(handler: @escaping (_ articles: [Article])-> ()){

    var articleArray = [Article]()
    REF_ARTICLES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (articleMessageSnapshot) in
        guard let articleMessageSnapshot = articleMessageSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

        for article in articleMessageSnapshot {

            let content = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "no content"
            let author = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "author").value as? String ?? "no author"
            let twitterHandle = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "twitterHandle").value as? String ?? "none"
            let articleTitle = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "articleTitle").value as? String ?? "no title"
            let date = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? "no date"

            let article = Article(content: content, author: author, twitterHandle: twitterHandle, ArticleTitle: articleTitle, date: date)
            articleArray.append(article)
        }
        handler(articleArray)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to add console log for articleMessageSnapshot ?

Comment: What mark asked and can you also confirm that `Article` has the author property?

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on similar app where i am storing data to firebase and retrieving. Below approach i used to fetch the data from firebase database. Please try once.

`func getAllArticles(handler: @escaping (_ articles: [Article])-> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("Articles").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("articles = \(snapshot)")
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let article = Article()
                article.articleTitle = dict["articleTitle"] as? String
                article.author = dict["author"] as? String
                article.twitterHandle = dict["twitterHandle"] as? String
                article.date = dict["date"] as? String
                article.content = dict["content"] as? String
                self.articleArray.append(article)
            }
            handler(articleArray)
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Please check out below code

```
var articleArray = [Article]()


        //REF_ARTICLES
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(“articles”)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                return
            }

            let articleObj = Article()
            articleObj.Content = dictionary["content"] as? String
            articleObj.Author = dictionary["author"] as? String
            articleObj.Twitterhandle = dictionary["twitterHandle"] as? String
            articleObj.Title = dictionary["articleTitle"] as? String
            articleObj.Date = dictionary["date"] as? String

            self. articleArray.append(articleObj)


        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the underlying issue was, but i fixed it by deleting "author" from the firebase tree and then adding it back